# My images are to small in mobile mode wordpress design

Tags: css, wordpress

In mobile mode the images are to small.  Do i have to go to custom css and add width?

I have add these codes but still have the problem. You can check it out here http://interstaff.se/wordpress/home

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

```
.example_image { 
width : 100% ;
maxwidth:190%; 
}
.example_image2 {
width : 100%;
max-width:190%;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html code, use punctuation and format your question to include punctuation and a proper link.

Comment: Can u go to the page and tell me what's wrong ??

Comment: Sure I can, and I have added that answer below, but the site works better for all when we follow the basic protocols. The better your question is asked and formatted, the more people see it, and the better answers you're likely to get.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be using a visual composer plugin based on the vc prefixes and it appears that you have a non-responsive setting checked.

As a result, you have the image in one column and the text in another.  Set a media query in your css to remove the float:left; and width: 50%; rules from the .vc_non_responsive .vc_row .vc_col-sm-6 elements and the columns will be full width and nicely stacked.

[image: all better!]